# Consuming Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I just started with rest services and i have read this https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/. Then according to this tutorial i have a service to consume and display.
The service is a rest api and i get  a json like that

```
 {
"disclaimer": "1",
"license": "2",
"timestamp": 1458057661,
"base": "someValue",
   "rates": {
     "one": 3.673019,
     "two": 68.449999,
   "three": 124.168,
  "four": 488.669996,
    ...,
     ...,
   ...
   }
}
```

Then i have created 2 Java class like that

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Cur {

private String disclaimer;
private String license;
private String timestamp;
private String base;    
private Rates rates;

public Cur() {
    super();
}

///get/set 


///tostring

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 public class Rates {

public Rates(){

    //// i am not sure here how  should i get the rates value.
   }

 }
```

the problem is how do i fill the Rates class to get the data into variables so that later i can present the on view.
I use RestTemplate. Here is the test.It works but i have no rates value.
I think i need a Map because rates  it's a collection.Any idea how to implement it.

```
@Test
public void getCurTest() { 
    String URL="some url";
    String JSONTYPE="some json type";
    String API="some id";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();         
    Cur cur= restTemplate.getForObject(URL+JSONTYPE+API, Cur.class);
    log.info("cur");        
    System.out.println(cur);
}
```

Comment: Look at the contents of the `"rates"` object in the JSON. What sort of data structure (think built-in ones) might you use to store a data set that looks like that?

Comment: This could be a map like key value but i am not sure.

Comment: What happens if you say that `rates` is a map?

Comment: I have also search and find this http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: A map will have rates values  like   key "one":   value 3.673019 but not sure about it

Comment: "Not sure" about what? Try it.

Comment: I have already try it and i still dont get the result i get an empty map.So either i have done something wrong  or i miss something.That 's why i ask here ..

Comment: If you are expecting a collection for rates, your json is incorrect.

Comment: json is correct it'working.

Comment: why is it downvoted? If you don't understand is let someone else to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same some years ago it's a little weird. Here what you can do.

First solution

The simple way is

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("your rest service api");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            String responseValue = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(responseValue);
        } else {
            // log error
        }
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
}
```

you can then get everything as a String and with regex parse it and get what you want.

Second solution

you can  save all your rest to a database as it is. Use mongodb for faster.
Then you can get it form there to a class and use it.

Third solution

use this tool  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/    just paste your json  and it will create  your java classes to use them. You can choose  what ever you want  to add.  This will create your classes then you can use them. 
Here for your convenience.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"disclaimer",
"license",
"timestamp",
"base",
"rates"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("disclaimer")
private String disclaimer;
@JsonProperty("license")
private String license;
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
private Integer timestamp;
@JsonProperty("base")
private String base;
@JsonProperty("rates")
private Rates rates;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
*
*/
public Example() {
}

/**
*
* @param timestamp
* @param disclaimer
* @param base
* @param rates
* @param license
*/
public Example(String disclaimer, String license, Integer timestamp, String base, Rates rates) {
this.disclaimer = disclaimer;
this.license = license;
this.timestamp = timestamp;
this.base = base;
this.rates = rates;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The disclaimer
*/
@JsonProperty("disclaimer")
public String getDisclaimer() {
return disclaimer;
}

/**
*
* @param disclaimer
* The disclaimer
*/
@JsonProperty("disclaimer")
public void setDisclaimer(String disclaimer) {
this.disclaimer = disclaimer;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The license
*/
@JsonProperty("license")
public String getLicense() {
return license;
}

/**
*
* @param license
* The license
*/
@JsonProperty("license")
public void setLicense(String license) {
this.license = license;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The timestamp
*/
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
public Integer getTimestamp() {
return timestamp;
}

/**
*
* @param timestamp
* The timestamp
*/
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
public void setTimestamp(Integer timestamp) {
this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The base
*/
@JsonProperty("base")
public String getBase() {
return base;
}

/**
*
* @param base
* The base
*/
@JsonProperty("base")
public void setBase(String base) {
this.base = base;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The rates
*/
@JsonProperty("rates")
public Rates getRates() {
return rates;
}

/**
*
* @param rates
* The rates
*/
@JsonProperty("rates")
public void setRates(Rates rates) {
this.rates = rates;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}


package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"one",
"two",
"three",
"four"
})
public class Rates {

@JsonProperty("one")
private Double one;
@JsonProperty("two")
private Double two;
@JsonProperty("three")
private Double three;
@JsonProperty("four")
private Double four;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
*
*/
public Rates() {
}

/**
*
* @param two
* @param one
* @param three
* @param four
*/
public Rates(Double one, Double two, Double three, Double four) {
this.one = one;
this.two = two;
this.three = three;
this.four = four;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The one
*/
@JsonProperty("one")
public Double getOne() {
return one;
}

/**
*
* @param one
* The one
*/
@JsonProperty("one")
public void setOne(Double one) {
this.one = one;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The two
*/
@JsonProperty("two")
public Double getTwo() {
return two;
}

/**
*
* @param two
* The two
*/
@JsonProperty("two")
public void setTwo(Double two) {
this.two = two;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The three
*/
@JsonProperty("three")
public Double getThree() {
return three;
}

/**
*
* @param three
* The three
*/
@JsonProperty("three")
public void setThree(Double three) {
this.three = three;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The four
*/
@JsonProperty("four")
public Double getFour() {
return four;
}

/**
*
* @param four
* The four
*/
@JsonProperty("four")
public void setFour(Double four) {
this.four = four;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Then you can use it as you want.

I hope all this helps. Take care.

Comment: @ GiorgoCh I have use the first one and it works.Thanks

Comment: Yes but also the  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  will do just fine what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way your JSON is, to get the Rates populed your class should look like this.

```
public class Cur {

    private String disclaimer;
    private String license;
    private Integer timestamp;
    private String base;
    private Rates rates;

}
```

---

```
public class Rates {

    private Double one;
    private Double two;
    private Double three;
    private Double four;
    //This would be better but the JSON dosnt fit this 
    //private Map<String, Double> rates;

}
```

Which API are you triyng to use?

Comment: @ Johanes have already tried this exaclty as you have it Exactly the same . But  i get an empty Map.So the problem is  how to get the rates values which can be from 1 to 1000 variables with values.

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: an Api for currency.I cannot say which one . Sorry.